# Django Authentication LDAP

Tags: python, django, ldap

I have a Django project in which I want to authenticate users against an Active Directory. Therefore, I am using the [django-python3-ldap](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap) framework. I am able to sync users(`./manage.py ldap_sync_users`), grant superuser admin access, and login to the default Django admin page using the framework as backend. However, when I try to authenticate on my site, the user state remains `AnonymousUser`.

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
try:
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user, backend=django_python3_ldap)
        context = {'user': user}
        return render(request, 'website/home.html', context)
    else:
        context = {'': ''}
        return render(request, 'website/login.html', context)
except:
    print()
```

**login.html**

```html
<!-- Main content -->
      <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
          <div class="hero-body">
              <div class="container has-text-centered">
                  <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
                      <div class="box">
                          <figure class="avatar">
                              <img src="">
                          </figure>
                          <form method="post">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="field">
                                  <div class="control">
                                      <input class="input is-large" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus="">
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="field">
                                  <div class="control">
                                      <input class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="field">
                                  <label class="checkbox">
                                      <input type="checkbox">
                                      Remember Me
                                  </label>
                              </div>
                              <button class="button is-block is-danger is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Login</button>
                              {% endblock %}
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </section>
```

**imports**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
import django_python3_ldap
```

**backend**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('login', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'website/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

Comment: There is not enough code shown to help. Where are you importing the authenticate and login methods from? Do you have the ldap backend set in settings? If you do you should be able to use the built in login view from django. It will call the correct authenticate.

Comment: @MitchellWalls see my edit. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I have provided an answer. I think you gave enough information initially, I just wasn't sure what login and authenticate you were using. I figured it was the django ones.

Comment: @MitchellWalls thank you for your help, I forgot the `name` attribute for my input objects. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: So what fixed it just curious?

Comment: @MitchellWalls I forgot to set the `name` attribute of my input objects, so when I referenced the form data after submission, objects with `name` = `username`/`password` were not found.

Answer (score 0):

I see possibly two issues the backend is not pointing to a valid backend. Also your try except is a bit dangerous please remove it. Unless you are testing never use a blank except. Use something like `except Exception as e: print(e)`. The reason I say that is the blank except was hiding the invalid backend error.

```
login(request, user, backend=django_python3_ldap)
# Should be
login(request, user, backend=django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend)
```

Comment: Good thoughts, I was using the blank except for testing purposes only, but thank you for the ideas.